# #1054 Unknown column peo.group

Tags: mysql

I know there are tons of questions listed with this type of question, and i've tried plenty in MySQL, but nothing seems to work. I hope it is just a minor error.

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS AcceptMeeting;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER AcceptMeeting
BEFORE INSERT ON participants
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF 'vip' IN (SELECT peo.group FROM people peo WHERE userid = NEW.pid)                                                                        
    AND 'tap' IN (SELECT pe.group FROM participants p, people pe, meetings m
                  WHERE m.meetid = p.meetid) 
    AND p.pid = pe.userid
    AND p.status = 'a' 

    THEN
        SET NEW.status = 'a';   

    END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

ERROR Code: 1054. Unknown column peo.group in field list.

Comment: What columns does the `people` table have?

Comment: Table People have the following attributes: name (VARCHAR), office (VARCHAR), userid (VARCHAR) and `group` (VARCHAR)

Answer (score 1):

`group` is reserved keyword in mysql

you should use backticks around it like that :

```
 `group`
```

Comment: I've tried `peo.group`, pe.`group` `peo.group` & `pe.group` .. Stil the same error :S .. I cant see it in the comment line. But every combination of backticks surrounding the group variables.

Comment: If this were the problem, I think it would complain of a syntax error, not an unknown column.

Comment: @user2824316 just a suggest , you dont need an alias `peo` in first query. because you dont use it.